# Which Italian accent sounds like this?

Tags: regional, pronunciation

The speaker in [this video](https://youtu.be/CziIiYHNh6Y?t=17) is Italian but has a "nonstandard" accent. He is speaking English in the clip, but the features of this accent are still clear.

Is anybody able to identify which region of Italy this accent is from?

### More details

I am not an expert at phonetics, but I believe I was able to identify some features of this accent:

1. It seems that he pronounces the "r", especially at the end of syllables, as a trill with 2 contacts. Many Italian speakers pronounce the "r" as a trill with one contact, so his "r" sounds a bit heavier.
2. His vowels seem to be more closed and are pronounced for a shorter duration compared to more standard accents.
3. His intonation seems to feature a smaller range of pitch changes when compared to more standard accents.

### Edit

Since more than one person in the comments has expressed doubt on whether the speaker is really Italian, I am including a screenshot from YouTube comments where he confirms it:

[image]

Comment: The accent in the video is certainly Southern. I am not sure I can be more precise than that (I am from the North and I find it hard to distinguish the various Southern accents). Your description is interesting because it does not feel Slavic at all to me.

Comment: How a language A sounds to person B depends on B as much as on A. So, unless one knows a whole lot about B's native tongue, the other languages they know, their education and so on, saying “sounds like” is utterly useless. I strongly suggest that you rephrase your question without mentioning Slavic languages and just asking what you desire to ask.

Comment: @DaG Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question.

Comment: It may be someone coming from Sardegna. Check this https://youtu.be/67NYVfIzP4g

Comment: Sorry, why do you think the speaker is Italian? The  accent is typical of  native Indian speaking in English to me. The emphatic way  they pronounce the “r” is typical of Indian speakers.

Comment: @Hachi The accent does not bare any resemblance to the Indian accent. Rolled "r"s appear in a myriad of other accents.

Comment: Note that the account name is "Gnorri TV", which seems unequivocally Italian in my view ([gnorri](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gnorri)).

Comment: @hb20007 - for business reasons I have  a lot of contacts with Indians who speak English and their accent is quite close to the one in the video. I really don’t see any reason why the speaker should be Italian.

Comment: @Hachi:    The audio in the video seems also English with Indian accent to me (in the past, I heard lots of Indians speaking English in Canary Islands).

Comment: @Charo Guys, he's Italian. I have added proof to my question.

Comment: @Hachi I added proof to my question

Comment: I’ve never heard the “r” pronounced that way in any Italian dialect. Maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: Might the person speaking in that video be “from Italy” as in, living in Italy, but Italian isn't their native tongue?

Comment: Nevertheless, [this](https://gnorri03.th-cam.com/) seems to be Thai.

Comment: @Charo That website (th-cam.com) seems to pirate videos from YouTube. They seem to create subdomains for each content creator they steal videos from, hence we have "gnorri03.th-cam.com". To anyone reading this, I would recommend not visiting the link since there is a chance it could be malicious. I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/letsplay/comments/fyfmub/what_is_thcam/ where some people on Reddit have reported their YouTube videos had been posted on that website.

Comment: Just to add confusion to the matter, “GnorriTV” has a peculiar way (in particular the Rs) of pronouncing Italian words and nouns too, for instance in his reviews of [_Africa addio_](https://youtu.be/MtEKX_EBJyo) or [_La grande guerra_](https://youtu.be/CziIiYHNh6Y).

Comment: @ Thanks, this is relevant information, and I have edited the question to link to one of those videos instead of the one I had initially

Comment: I appreciate that you have edited the question, and personally am dubious about the “GnorriTV”'s answer (his answer on YouTube is not necessarily reliable, nor a conclusive answer to the question here). But since you have “accepted” your own answer, likely this question won't attract much more attention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reached out to the person from the video by posting a comment on one of his latest videos. I asked him what part of Italy he's from, and he was kind enough to reply:

[image: GnorriTV reply]

It's also worth noting that the accent sounds Southern to several Italians who I asked.

Comment: I'm from Central Italy, and this is certainly no typical “Central Italian English”. I wonder what he means by “milder”... EDIT: I just asked him.